# Filtering Berkeley Research Scanning Nginx logs with Logcheck

Tags: nginx, regex

I'm getting Nginx log entries from http://researchscan1.eecs.berkeley.edu/ (and others), with lots of special characters in the requests, which I'm trying to filter out. E.g.:

```
2016/07/19 09:54:49 [error] 2006#2006: *5878 testing "//http" existence failed (2: No such file or directory) while logging request, client: 169.229.3.91, server: common.example.co.uk, request: "J/¤nkb=© 2]rµÐ[‘lç¢î­/€@I"-
2016/07/19 11:29:05 [error] 2007#2007: *5945 testing "//http" existence failed (2: No such file or directory) while logging request, client: 169.229.3.91, server: common.example.co.uk, request: "i•jœ»@d‹˜þˆ¿–j•c|B‹¤¯Dñ½°|ôáV*Õ8ÓãÎð€í)ÑYCæôì    £¶›¬Dxîoÿv.N"
```

My usual Logcheck regex for these kind of requests:

```
^[[:digit:]]{4}/[[:digit:]]{2}/[[:digit:]]{2} [[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2} \[error\] [#[:digit:]]+: \*[[:digit:]]+ testing .+ existence failed \(2: No such file or directory\) while logging request, .+$
```

isn't catching them. I've tried:

```
^[[:digit:]]{4}/[[:digit:]]{2}/[[:digit:]]{2} [[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2} \[error\] [#[:digit:]]+: \*[[:digit:]]+ testing .+ existence failed \(2: No such file or directory\) while logging request, (.|[[:cntrl:]])+$
```

but no luck. Both variations match the log entries in RegexBuddy set to POSIX ERE. Are any Logcheck/regular expressions experts able to help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your slashes. I mean the slashes, that separate the date.

```
^[[:digit:]]{4}\/[[:digit:]]{2}\/[[:digit:]]{2} [[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2} \[error\] [#[:digit:]]+: \*[[:digit:]]+ testing .+ existence failed \(2: No such file or directory\) while logging request, .+$
```

Then, your usual expression works fine for me even with that special chars at the end.

Comment: Hi, works for you in Logcheck, or another regex flavour? I ask because in some languages you'll need to escape the forward slash as its used as a delimiter. It isn't a special character in regular expressions though, and I don't believe this is needed in Logcheck.